# spark Scala simple addition and other mathematical calculation

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

Hi I am new to apache Spark, In my use case I will be having 3 inputs ,all present in HDFS, I need to extract the data from file present in hdfs and add two datas and will divide the result with third data, How can i proceed?

Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: Do you mean you want to add the first element of A to the first element of B, and so on? `A.zip(B).map(case (a, b) => (a+b)/C)` looks like it should do what you want.

Comment: Also note you can extract the 4th (or 3rd) element of your split array in the first map, rather than mapping over everything again.

Comment: As you can see val A data is extracted from file a.dat and val B data is extracted from b.dat and I should add A and B and multiply with c and divide with 12.

Comment: But you've not really answered my question, just repeated what you already said in your original question. A (and B) is an RDD and so contains many rows, each with a value. Do you want the values added (and then devided by C), first to first, second to second and so on? If so that's what my code suggestion does

Comment: For example a.dat contains r(0) which is considered as key and all other r(1),r(2),r(3),r(4) are values and in b.dat i am having r(0),r(1),r(2),r(3),r(4). where r(1) is key and all others are values , keeping r(0) in a.dat and r(1) in b.dat as key i need to add r(4) in a.dat with r(3) in b.dat , i need to get the value of the result of adding r(4)+ r(3) without key and the result should be multiplied with C and the multiplied result should be divided with 12. A+B*C/12 simple way to explain.

Comment: Then that's a) different from your question, which divides by C, and b) what I wrote does what you said you wanted. Try `A.zip(B).map(case (a, b) => (a+b)*C/12)`, then. That will give you an RDD where each row is calculated from the r(4) and r(3) of each row taken from A and B

Comment: I tried using the A.zip(B).map(case (a, b) => (a+b)*C/12), but its throwing error that C should be an INT when I mapped as a key value pair its showing type mismatch found (string,string)required string in the field b

Comment: Post your code, I'm not telepathic

Comment: No, edit your question and put the code thre.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
  import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
  import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
  import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
  import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD

  val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("spark-scratch").setMaster("local")
  val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

  val A = sc.textFile("/user/root/spark/cc.dat").map(_.split(",")).map(fc => (fc(3).toInt))
  val B = sc.textFile("/user/root/spark/aci.dat").map(_.split(",")).map(fc => (fc(4).toInt))
  val C = sc.textFile("/user/root/spark/bta.dat").map(_.split(",")).map(fc => (fc(5).toInt))

  val calc = { r: ((Int, Int), Int) =>
    val ((a, b), c) = r
    a * b * c / 12
  }

  val result = (A zip B zip C).map(calc)
```

(it compiles, but I didn't test it)